# How to change all objects within a S3 bucket to reduced redundancy

Tags: bash, amazon-s3

I'd like to know if there is a bucket wide (not per object) way of doing this.

Thank you!

Comment: A way of doing what? Using what tooling (does it matter)? I'm not sure this is appropriate for this site. This might be more appropriate for https://superuser.com/ .

Comment: Thank you, I will check on superuser as well, regarding the tooling, s3cmd / python / anything would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript for browser I am using this;

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'bucket'}});
    s3.listObjects({Prefix: ""}, function (err, data) {
        if (data.Contents.length) {
           async.each(data.Contents, function (file, cb) {
               var params = {
                       CopySource: 'bucket' + '/' + file.Key,
                       Key: file.Key,
                       StorageClass: 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
                    };
              s3.copyObject(params, function (copyErr, copyData) {
                  if (copyErr) { 
                         console.log(err);
                     } else {
           console.log('Changed to REDUCED_REDUNDANCY: ',params.CopySource);
                     }
                 });
               });
           }
    });
```

Here getList of objects in a bucket, copy and paste each object in same place asyncronuously with a little change; STANDARD to REDUCED_REDUNDANCY. If nothing changed, you cannot copy/paste in the same place and you get error in console.